# Python Contingency Table

Tags: python, numpy, information-theory

I am generating many, many contingency tables as part of a project that I'm writing.

The workflow is:

- Take a large data array with continuous (float) rows and convert those to discrete integer values by binning (so that the resulting row has values 0-9, for example)
- Slice two rows into vectors X & Y and generate a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) from them, so that I have the 2-dimensional frequency distribution
- For example, I'd have a 10 x 10 array, counting the number of (xi, yi) that occur
- Use the contingency table to do some information theory math

Initially, I wrote this as:

```
def make_table(x, y, num_bins):
    ctable = np.zeros((num_bins, num_bins), dtype=np.dtype(int))
    for xn, yn in zip(x, y):
        ctable[xn, yn] += 1
    return ctable
```

This works fine, but is so slow that it's eating up like 90% of the runtime of the entire project.

The fastest python-only optimization I've been able to come up with is this:

```
def make_table(x, y, num_bins):
    ctable = np.zeros(num_bins ** 2, dtype=np.dtype(int))
    reindex = np.dot(np.stack((x, y)).transpose(), 
                     np.array([num_bins, 1]))
    idx, count = np.unique(reindex, return_counts=True)
    for i, c in zip(idx, count):
        ctable[i] = c
    return ctable.reshape((num_bins, num_bins))
```

That's (somehow) a lot faster, but it's still pretty expensive for something that doesn't seem like it should be a bottleneck. Are there any efficient ways to do this that I'm just not seeing, or should I just give up and do this in cython?

Also, here's a benchmarking function.

```
def timetable(func):
    size = 5000
    bins = 10
    repeat = 1000
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(repeat):
        x = np.random.randint(0, bins, size=size)
        y = np.random.randint(0, bins, size=size)
        func(x, y, bins)
    end = time.time()
    print("Func {na}: {ti} Ms".format(na=func.__name__, ti=(end - start)))
```

Comment: Other than Cython, you might also want to consider Numba (https://numba.pydata.org/) -- which one does the job better will vary, but Numba can be a bit easier to get up and running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clever trick for representing the elements of `np.stack((x, y))` as integers can be made faster:

```
In [92]: %timeit np.dot(np.stack((x, y)).transpose(), np.array([bins, 1]))
109 µs ± 6.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [94]: %timeit bins*x + y
12.1 µs ± 260 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Moreover, the last part of your second solution can be simplified somewhat, by simply considering

```
np.unique(bins * x + y, return_counts=True)[1].reshape((bins, bins))
```

What is more, since we are dealing with equally spaced non-negative integers, [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) will outperform `np.unique`; with that, the above boils down to

```
np.bincount(bins * x + y).reshape((bins, bins))
```

All in all, this provides quite some performance over what you are currently doing:

```
In [78]: %timeit make_table(x, y, bins)  # Your first solution
3.86 ms ± 159 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [79]: %timeit make_table2(x, y, bins)  # Your second solution
443 µs ± 23.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [101]: %timeit np.unique(bins * x + y, return_counts=True)[1].reshape((bins, bins))
307 µs ± 25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [118]: %timeit np.bincount(bins * x + y).reshape((10, 10))
30.3 µs ± 3.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

You may also want to be aware of [`np.histogramdd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html#numpy.histogramdd) which takes care of both rounding and binning at once, although it's likely going to be slower than rounding and using `np.bincount`.

Comment: Very nicely done - this was an order of magnitude better.  
  
`np.bincount(bins * x + y).reshape((bins, bins))`  
  
Just as an added note, it needed a bit of a change to deal with 0s in the table:  

`np.bincount(bins * x + y, minlength=bins ** 2).reshape((bins, bins))`  
This worked perfectly, passed testing and was quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

This answer merely extends fuglede's answer to the case where x and y may be discretized into different numbers of bins. It does assume that the categories for x and y are numbered `0, 1, ..., n_bins_x` and `0, 1, ..., n_bins_y`, respectively.

```
def make_table(x, y):
    n_bins_x = np.max(x) + 1
    n_bins_y = np.max(y) + 1
    tab = np.bincount(
        n_bins_y * x + y, minlength=n_bins_x * n_bins_y
    ).reshape((n_bins_x, n_bins_y))
    return tab
```