# Fast counting of feature values in Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: python, numpy, naivebayes

I am implementing a Naive Bayes classifier in Python (as part of a university assignment, so Python is a requirement). I got it to work and it produces about the same result as `sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB`. However, it's really slow compared to the sklearn implementation.

Suppose feature values are integers in the range of 0 to max_i, and class labels are also integers in the range of 0 to max_y. An example dataset looks like this:

```
>>> X = np.array([2,1 1,2 2,2 0,2]).reshape(4,2) # design matrix
>>> print(X)
[[2 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 2]
 [0 2]]
>>> y = np.array([0,  1,  2,  0  ]) # class labels
>>> print(y)
[0 1 2 0]
```

Now, as an intermediate step before dealing with the joint log likelihood, I need to compute class conditional likelihoods (i.e. `P(x_ij | y)` such that a matrix `ccl` contains the probability of value k in feature j given class c. The output of such a matrix for the example above would be:

```
>>> print(ccl)
[[[0.5 0.  0.5]
  [0.  0.5 0.5]]

 [[0.  1.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  1. ]]

 [[0.  0.  1. ]
  [0.  0.  1. ]]]
>>> print(ccl[0][1][1]) # prob. of value 1 in feature 1 given class 0
0.5
```

The code I implemented to achieve this looks like this:

```
N, D = X.shape
K = np.max(X)+1
C = np.max(y)+1
ccl = np.zeros((C,D,K))
# ccl = ccl + alpha - 1 # disregard the dirichlet prior for this question
# Count occurences of feature values given class c
for i in range(N):
    for d in range(D):
        ccl[y[i]][d][X[i][d]] += 1
# Renormalize so it becomes a probability distribution again
for c in range(C):
    for d in range(D):
        cls[c][d] = np.divide(cls[c][d], np.sum(cls[c][d]))
```

So since Python loops are slow, this also becomes slow.
I tried to mitigate this problem by one-hot encoding every feature value (so if the feature values are in range [0,1,2], a 2 becomes: [0,0,1] and so on.) and summing up like this. Although, I think too many np functions are called so the computation still takes too long:

```
ccl = np.zeros((C,D,K))
for c in range(C):
    x = np.eye(K)[X[np.where(y==c)]] # one hot encoding
    ccl[c] += np.sum(x, axis=0) # summing up
    ccl[c] /= ccl[c].sum(axis=1)[:, numpy.newaxis] # renormalization
```

This would result in the same output as above. Any hints on how to make this faster? I think `np.eye` (the one-hot encoding) is unnecessary and kills it but I can't think of a way to get rid of it. One last thing I considered is using `np.unique()` or `collections.Counter` for counting but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a pretty neat problem (and I had a [similar problem not that long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294382/python-contingency-table)). It looks like the fastest way to handle this is usually to construct an index array using just arithmetic operations and then pile it up and reshape it with `np.bincount`.

```
N, D = X.shape
K = np.max(X) + 1
C = np.max(y) + 1
ccl = np.tile(y, D) * D * K + (X +  np.tile(K * range(D), (N,1))).T.flatten()
ccl = np.bincount(ccl, minlength=C*D*K).reshape(C, D, K)
ccl = np.divide(ccl, np.sum(ccl, axis=2)[:, :, np.newaxis])

>>> ccl
array([[[0.5, 0. , 0.5],
        [0. , 0.5, 0.5]],

       [[0. , 1. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 1. ]],

       [[0. , 0. , 1. ],
        [0. , 0. , 1. ]]])
```

As a comparison for speed, `funca` is your first loop-based method, `funcb` is your second numpy function-based method, and `funcc` is the method using bincount.

```
X = np.random.randint(3, size=(10000,2))
y = np.random.randint(3, size=(10000))
>>> timeit.timeit('funca(X,y)', number=100, setup="from __main__ import funca, X, y")
2.632569645998956
>>> timeit.timeit('funcb(X,y)', number=100, setup="from __main__ import funcb, X, y")
0.10547748399949342
>>> timeit.timeit('funcc(X,y)', number=100, setup="from __main__ import funcc, X, y")
0.03524605900020106
```

It might be possible to further refine this, but I don't have any more good ideas.

Comment: Hi @CJ59, thank you very much for your answer! Sorry that it took me almost 3 weeks to mark it as accepted. I was busy and meanwhile also tried some other methods, but yours is still the fastest. Thank you again